# Jmeter: Use the same ConnectionFactory for Multiple threads while posting JMS messages

Tags: java, jms, jmeter

I am using the JMS point-to-point sampler of Jmeter to test the performance if a large number of JMS messages are posted on to a Queue.

The Jmeter at present creates a new **QueueConnectionFactory** and **QueueConnection** for each of the thread ( as per the number of threads provided) . I guess this is not how it happens via the front end, where a single connection factory handles different threads.

How do we make sure that it creates only one connection for all the threads? Is there any option in Jmeter? Or should we modify the code? It would be nice if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 2.7, JMeter does not have an option to create one QueueConnection and share it accross threads. 
Only InitialContext is cached.

I opened an enhancement request on [JMeter Bugzilla](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&bug_severity=Enhancement&product=JMeter&order=Bug%20Number&list_id=88553):

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53833

Regarding what you say about real life, it really depends on what is simulated:

- If you want to simulate one application using one broker then what you say is true
- But if you want to simulate many application using one broker, then current JMeter approach is closer to reality.

Regards

Philippe M.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done if I can rope in a Java expert and modify the existing code of the Jmeter? How difficult can it be to implement? And is  there a chance someone might have already implemented it and I can search for the same?

Comment: I opened the enhancement, either you wait for somebody or the team to implement it, either you absolutely need it and an expert will be able to do so then submit a patch.

Comment: Thanks. Typically how long will it take for them to fix it (if at all they' be fixing it) ?

Comment: You cannot tell, it's an open source project where team members work on their free time.